# Slower animation when run in device (iPad) compare to iPad Simulator

Tags: ipad, animation, core-animation, bezier, uibezierpath

My program is a grid view of products, when clicked, the image animates from the original position going to the desired destination (position in view controller). When I run it in the iPad Simulator, the image will start to animate instantly without delay but when I run it in the device (iPad) it's giving me roughly 1 second delay before it starts to animate..

Here's my code. I'm using bezier path.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.1 
                     animations:^{
                         UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
                         [movePath moveToPoint:cellImageView.center];
                         [movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:self.miniDropHereView.center
                                          controlPoint:CGPointMake(self.miniDropHereView.center.x, cellImageView.center.y)];


                         CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
                         moveAnim.path = movePath.CGPath;
                         moveAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;


                         CABasicAnimation *scaleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
                         scaleAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
                         scaleAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1.0)];
                         scaleAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

                         CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"alpha"];
                         opacityAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
                         opacityAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1];
                         opacityAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

                         CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
                         animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim, scaleAnim, opacityAnim, nil];
                         animGroup.duration = 1;
                         [cellImageView.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:@"angelica"];
                         cellImageView.alpha = 0; //.0000000000000000000001;

                         self.animateProduct = animGroup;
                         self.cellImageViewGlobal = cellImageView;
                         self.animateProduct.delegate= self;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         cellImageView.alpha = 0.0000000000000000000001;
                         [cellImageView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

I researched how to manipulate the delay before the animation starts. So I change the first line of the animation code (specified below)

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.1 delay: 0.0f
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                         animations:^{
```

But even if I haven't specified the delay, the start of the animation happens instantly, right after i click the products (when using iPad Simulator). I'm not sure if the problem is my iPad. Are there any other ways to speed up the start of the animation?

Thanks.

Comment: A iPad uses a slower CPU and memory system than does a contemporaneous Mac.

Comment: thanks.. but are there any other ways to speed it up? Like revise some parts of my code. or add something that will help it speed up?

Answer (score 0):

You're using CABasicAnimation and CAAnimationGroup objects in the body of a view-based animation (UIView animateWithDuration:animations and it's variants). Don't do that. I'm surprised it works at all. It's certainly not the right way to do animation.

Get rid of your call to UIView animateWithDuration:animations: and use your CAAnimation group directly.